# ASP .NET MVC Formulario con campo "Imagen" - Cargar una imagen en la "Vista" e insertarla en la DB

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo configurado la conexión a la base de datos para la tabla "Eventos"
[image: Conexion Ado]

El cual me genera los campos en el modelo, y en el campo Imagen me lo transforma a tipo "byte"

```
    public byte[] Imagen { get; set; }
```

En la vista tengo configurado el campo "Imagen" de esta forma

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Imagen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Como debo configurar el campo en la "Vista" para que cuando se adjunte la imagen y cuando ejecute el metodo "Create", se registra la imagen en SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer varios pasos:

1) Crea tu formulario con el atributo enctype = "multipart/form-data" y agrega un elemento input tipo file con el atributo name diferente al de la propiedad Imagen (Ver código de la vista).

2) En tu action method POST del controller, crea un parámetro HttpPostedFileBase, con un nombre igual al del input, para que se mapee el campo automáticamente. Y finalmente convierte el HttpPostedFileBase a un array de bytes. Con esto ya luego aplicas tu lógica de BD.

Este código te servirá de guía.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Imagen2() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Imagen2(HttpPostedFileBase img, Evento evt) {
        using(var reader = new BinaryReader(img.InputStream)) {
            evt.Imagen = reader.ReadBytes(img.ContentLength);
        }

        // Aquí tu lógica de negocio y BD.

        return View();
    }
}
```

Y tu vista (revisa los elementos input y form):

```
@model MvcApp.Controllers.Evento
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Imagen2</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Imagen2", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Imagen)
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("img", null, new {type = "file"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagen, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <button>Enviar</button>
    }
</body>
</html>
```